# Why is my LED circuit drawing 50% more mA than I calculated?

Tags: led, resistors

I am having trouble with an LED circuit I am designing.

I am supplying 24 volts from a benchtop supply and have 7 blue LEDs ([datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/CREE%20Power/C503B-BCS_BCN_GCS_GCN_2019.pdf)) and an 82 ohm resistor in series.

I calculated that with a forward voltage of 3.2V and a 20mA forward current I would need an 82 ohm resistor and my circuit should draw 20mA.  According to my supply I am drawing around 30ma.

I tried with a digital multimeter and got the same result.

What am I missing? Is it just possible that both of my meters are wrong, or is this to be expected and this is just fine?

Ultimately this will be a flashing light bar for an RC car.

I included the transistor in the schematic below but even when I isolate just the LED and resistor part of the circuit I run into the same issue.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: You've measured the current. Now measure the voltage drop across each LED and see if you're 3.2 V forward voltage you used in your calculation is correct. Report back!

Comment: What did you get when you measured the supply voltage, voltage across each LED, and voltage across the resistor? What power supply will you use with the RC car?

Comment: Your calculation was correct if you assume Vce for Q1 is 0V and sum of all forward voltages across all diodes is 22.4V. I am guessing that the sum of forward voltages is a bit less, and consequently, the current is a bit higher than you expected. You could use some other simple current source type of drive to make the circuit less sensitive to diode forward voltage if you want.

Comment: Providing alternate circuits is certainly off-topic to the question of "why does this circuit not work the way I thought". Others have mentioned why using a constant-current driver is preferable. Here's a quick note to get your mind started: https://www.bristolwatch.com/sr/cc_led.htm Using a cheap LM317 as a constant-current LED driver.

Comment: @spuck no it's not. Especially when others have addressed the other part of the question. Alternative circuits do answer the root issue of circuit bad.

Comment: Just my thought, but would it not make sense to connect the LEDs in parallel? That way you just have to regulate the input voltage, and the loss of a single LED will not kill the whole circuit. With just the 7 in this example, series connect could work, but make a line of dozens of them and your voltages and error margins become unmanageable. Even with just 7,  the OP will experience greater drift in the voltage drop due to environment temperature than the observed deviation.

Comment: What is the LED signal that you are using to drive the transistor? Is it a simple voltage pulse?

Comment: @PcMan The problem of putting diodes in parallel is current sharing. Each diode will have a slightly different voltage drop so some will take more current than others. The brightness of an LED depends on current, so this will make some brighter and some dimmer. Putting them in series ensures that they all have equal current,

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is almost certainly within tolerance of expected behavior for these LEDs.

A quick way to see this is to do a back-of-the-envelope sensitivity analysis.

What's the current if the LED forward voltage drops are exactly 3.2 V each (the datasheet "typical" value)?

$$\frac {24 \ \text{V} - 7 \cdot 3.2 \ \text{V}} {82 \ \Omega} = 19.5 \ \text{mA}$$

What happens if the LED forward voltage drop is only 3.1 V each (an insignificant 0.1 V difference from a manufacturing tolerance perspective, since they're only promising 3.2 V typ and 4.0 V max)?

$$\frac {24 \ \text{V} - 7 \cdot 3.1 \ \text{V}} {82 \ \Omega} = 28.0 \ \text{mA}$$

So for your circuit design, we get +44% more current if the LED forward voltage drop is off by just 0.1 V.

(This analysis neglects the fact that the higher current would cause a slightly higher voltage drop than it would at the specified 20mA. However, it still shows that the overall current is very sensitive to the LED voltage drop.)

Comment: I measured each LED in my test circuit and found the voltage drop to be around 2.97v. I did my math over and came up with 180ohm which is actually what I already found worked to get the current draw I desired. Now I know why that was. I will have to do some more research into the other suggestions and try them put as well.

Comment: Just as an addition: your resistor may have a variation vs nominal value as well. Typical ±20% tolerance would cause 16...35 mA range if combined with the LEDs variance mentioned above. That way, a trim pot is inevitable if you plan to achieve precise current.

Comment: @YurySchkatula: 20% resistors have been obsolete for decades, and even 10% are rare these days.  Even the common "5%" resistors will often be within 1% of their marked value.

Answer (score 25):

Your calculation probably went something like this. Seven LEDs at 3.2 V each is 22.4 V dropped, leaving 1.6 V across a 82 Ω resistor is about 20 mA.

Unfortunately the LED forward voltage is only approximate, that's some of what the 'typical' means in the data sheet. The drop varies with temperature too. If it was 3.1 V per LED, then the forward drop would be 21.7 V, leaving 2.3 V across the resistor, for a current of nearly 30 mA.

This is why LEDs are usually driven from constant current drivers, rather than constant voltage drivers. If you are going to try to simulate a constant current source with a resistor, then you need a much larger relative voltage drop on the resistor to swamp the change in LED voltage, which of course means an inefficient solution.

Comment: You hit the key point with your 2nd paragraph. Powering LEDs with CV supply through a limiting resistor is a poor-man's approximation of a CC source. It's only good for indicator LEDs, where efficiency is not paramount and you can afford to drop a fair amount of the supply voltage across the resistor (and you don't care about exact current levels anyway). For LED lighting is either too inefficient or not a good approximation, i.e. the current depends more on the LEDs characteristics than the  value of the resistor.

Answer (score 18):

Alternate CC source suitable for  LEDs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Q7Ma.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is chosen so that Q1 Vbe of about 0.7V is achieved at the desired LED current.

R2 supplies the base current for Q2 (the pass transistor).

Q1 diverts the base current from Q2 when the LED current is at the desired level, throttling Q2's collector current.

Power dissipation of Q2 may be of concern. A 200mW limit at 20mA would allow up to 10V to be dropped across the LEDs- certainly more than sufficient in this case.

Comment: Note that since you want a control signal, you can 'flip' the circuit using NPN transistors such as 2N4401 and replace R2 with lower value to correspond to the control voltage (eg. 6.8K for 5V). That saves you the drive transistor.

Answer (score 13):

tl; dr: skip to the end for the **low-side 2-transistor current limiter**.

**What's the problem?**

The LED forward voltage (**Vf**) will vary from LED to LED, and with overall forward current. This Vf may be significantly different than the stated Vf in the datasheet.

The total LED current is calculated as follows:

- I(led) = (Vcc - Total Vf) / R

Some quick math on several Vf points (Vcc = 24V for all):

- Total Vf = (**3.2V** * 7), R = 82 ohm: IR drop is 1.6V, current is **19.5mA**
- Total Vf = (**3.1V** * 7), R = 82 ohm: IR drop is 2.3V, current is **28.0mA**
- Total Vf = (**3.0V** * 7), R = 82 ohm: IR drop is 3.0V, current is **36.6mA**

The takeaway: a small change in the average Vf, multiplied by the total LEDs in the string, makes a big difference in the IR drop across the resistor (and thus, the current): nearly 2:1 for just a 0.2V difference in average Vf. This is because you're trying to make the resistor IR drop as small as possible, while laudable, makes the current vary by a lot.

You can adjust the dropping resistor to get the current you want as a one-time deal and get on with life. However, as it so happens, you have most of a solution in-hand to make a *constant-current* driver to compensate for this variation.

Let the hacking commence...

**Emitter-Follower Constant-Current Driver**

Here's a workable, minimum-components constant-current driver that uses the NPN low-side switch as a crude current limiter ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgB3EbBFETPjz4o8eKJ34ZhUycISFxXAd16zukGopWDVyoeOyaAZhwAmAJwD2ABwA6AR2zQUTehGLRsKZqyiwafITQNDTEcAEohvIIYMRIVDCQKGxghHxgIuCZqVQZYnwmFjYOTi70CeB%20kOyp6YS52cTpmQVmVnaOzq5QPRCJNWngTVn5KJp5-CCF7SVd5b1VA8JjI-zyq61FHaXdFX2wS2sKEyJiJ1NtxZ1lPbmLKYOnq14N%20Rdbszd797XcaM%20qc7TK47eZ3fpsABKqwmEzwFSoNCoKwR0AQEn0E30aDEkDY2EIZ2GKHWsWE%20FuEjAISOQzkCjx2AwVGIChJxxp7MqCXxzO0-Ap2KR3PEABkQKzaYRNFy7kYAIYAGwAzgxuJ4tMouS9aXjzGouWTdSBCXA2ABzfn6a2Eyn67GiK2qZEYNgAFz%20yPW2PWdyYMB4YAwsWD2DwxDoMXi0EIOCRJJihIjTWIyCopgYCoAroq3Wx9VqZHoNL00GagA)):

[image]

You can change the current by changing either the voltage divider setpoint or the emitter resistor. If your logic is 5V, also adjust accordingly.

- Good: minimum components count (just 1 transistor and 3 resistors)
- Bad: influenced by transistor beta, needs adjusting

For greater current accuracy, there's some other approaches to making constant current.

**Buffered Current-Sensing Driver With Op-amp**

This adds an op-amp which senses the low-side current and adjusts the NPN drive. ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcZoIQDgCwCYsOwOxjoEBsBICkll1CApgLRhgBQATiM6dWLl6Uzh%201bNnisASlz7oQAZmwyRUVZlFDqW1KwAuIdL0xDZ4Y6oiMY8kugCcVQenml5DijHK5SpLL4SYCOQQYHAgACb0AGYAhgCuADa6HMJy2Oqp4HZKogSsAOaZ6bz82EGqkKwx4KRmQoZ1IHbgSMxIofBhMAFgGOhlkAhEBAQ5qJhgPJBuCHyEmKRKHRIA7jU1WhtQrGu8PBbZ22umkyVyYIeVhYyCIMUCQmW1WjvrpjcmInpciuBkD39nuAKuNTtMHHMCAslmFIrFEsk1h9GsjTJUkbcLkpkfd0T8lv9GL8wOY8USluZUaTXlShKj9njeIcTpdWAAZLhiT5yRhPTK8ECxBIAZ3oCmg8m28gIZyatRO-AgL3kQiiK3C7AA9gAHAA6AEd5NBsLzgXYJdgmCwoLAcCBSNBjHY4DhsCqgrMHCDINhWJNsSwlL9GA1fko1RqdQajSachYbZA2EjTMHAwocn7FlxQ9jMHIw4L1Vq9YbjabNkrYGx-Vw8%20mZLUCxHi9Gy3GBTBE5mA42lr27oXIyWY%20X453q1nJvW602i1HS7GKsDx92QDOlDmB835yP28uq6vN2nZ0PW4uKwmk8gg0t%20L88Snb3I7M9WNLqMxmfxuLKlUcZF%20PJcvyb6%20Jy6SZLyEENC8QA)):

[image]

Design note: this uses a transistor is wired as a Vbe reference, making it mostly insensitive to the logic voltage. You can also use a voltage divider and save the 1 transistor.

Of all the proposals shown here it's the most accurate.

- Good: Very accurate. transistor beta doesn't affect it. Doesn't care about switching voltage
- Bad: op-amp cost (about 25 to 50 cents for a single-ended type like an LM321.)

**2-Transistor Current Limiter**

@Spehro's example uses two PNP transistors. Starting with this I tweaked the values a bit to reduce the reference bias current and added logic control. I then made a version using two NPN's and low-side control.

Here's the two versions: using a high-side (like Spehro's) with a switch control, and a version using a low-side current sink. [Simulate them both here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgB3cDQkbbXmB59INKG2wYqeKphQgZIsRCqQJYgGYcAJgCcA9gAcAOgEds0FE3oRi0bCmasosGvMLQaNYnDcpsNAiECGDESKqwKGxghPICeHwCtHCJvPJaekZmFlb0quAukOwxcUn8vPGpIOk6BibmltZQzSqwxbFKVeVVNZn1OU35rUXRHXJdoj0gGXXZjXkthe3yKDRU3eMb07VZDbnNVMPL1fg9a1MzuwMLh0uj8kIVSWgJW5f98wcFMCNca%20tJf58BDyNRcR7cQTCUKgziQ%20GsB7CMEKQ5geSKGKqOEQxGo8Do8SSQ7CcYQ3DKA5sAAyIBYFTQdJor0Ztw0AEMADYAZwYfHs4l0tBZVHpfFZ1TQagA5sl1iC5XxCAlsQAXYXi6TrCWtQjwDBgbDEZXBMA0MDhaCxM2QFBEbwYPAIZ02FLaBgcgCunNVbCFuMJuOR1QwbFlim6EYV2KFihe%20PGVGV8DYACUEYHhIp8udVl8YAg4XHTmaxPGUZjiBjZKc1Oq8RDMcGWC5CBgUGQQd5bWEAnSC3QCIQHJAyMPRK6qO6vT62PWvCcEhDy3TWtgZOOaG3RDEeDRyEwYG2Oxguz4Owg%202A3R72d7feDSXnl%203xFwcGk8AkP50UcFPwk-4hrCXBAZUYGsnCP7gUESoqnCyqvJM0GTHWICIZ0YGoQUh5Wu2Bp6l%203h4N4zouJeJGsJAbYyNReChMgU63ve9wUIGC4IAupbVNsfRzPsQx3CUFBcRx0ILr0sx7IMiw-McCDiWIhHgBJvFSdcXxHKxyncYQ5zcZJVyfIJcnafpC7HipZZqUZAmyW02mvtxUjKKp7z8TJtymcJLlWSAP4GTZHx2V5DnpiEDwcYSxpfLmYj5AWUFJM5zx5molQKWkr6ZZK8VvhQKAJOMOWJhIUjCrI2WFcB3xEuVP52mIDWwSo4i0sylXyF4RWvmyXK8vyeQIbB4y%20aVQpAcVpK9ehtFhv5ZTKgtFQkVSQooU1i0qiGc7%20ZMo3PDNEC4UaG5EIVeDKm4X6tvhWJEcQJFhEg15MTOvpAA)

[image]

Let's compare.

High Side:

- Good: Compensates for beta. Doesn't care about logic voltage.
- Bad: switched bias consumes an extra 7.6mW. Takes 3 transistors.

Low Side:

- Good: Compensates for beta. less power consumed in bias current. Needs just 2 transistors.
- Bad: Sensitive to logic voltage, requires adjustment if other than 3.3V.

Of all these, the **low-side current limiter solution** gives the best bang-for-buck in accuracy, beta insensitivity and cost.

Comment: For circuit two, assuming the 24V is regulated, you could replace the transistor with a resistor and just rely on the voltage divider effect to set the voltage. Also, you could get rid fo the op-amp and just connect the divider directly to the BJT if great precision is not needed.

Comment: The op-amp cancels any beta variation. I also wanted to show the idea of a band gap reference, but yes it could be done with a divider too.

Comment: What’s missing in both of these is a control.

Comment: I doubt the first circuit is thermally stable using discrete BJTs, especially if they get hot. That current mirror relies on the Vbe of the two transistor to be matched and thermally coupled, so that they remain matched when temperature varies. It might work if the two BJTs are the same model, come from the same batch and are mounted together on the same heat-sink or glued together.

Comment: It’s crap, but better than nothing. The op-amp approach fixes that.

Comment: All right, heavy revision and added a means to control.

Comment: This seems... excessive. For a one off toy car.

Comment: One extra resistor? Hardly.

Comment: I'm looking at some circuits to drive LEDs when I found your post. I'm trying to simulate your example circuits in LTspice, but I can't get the LED currents that you show. I was wondering what transistors would you recommend using to replicate your model and what SPICE parameters you would use to model the LED? To be more specific, you got mA where I got microamps. That's how far off I am.

Comment: The Falstad model uses a generic beta=100 type. The first, simplest model will need adjustment for the beta as the divider splits the current between the low side resistor and the base. The other models should not be as sensitive to beta.

Comment: Check the Vf of your diodes - the overall Vf needs to be less than (Vcc- (minimum Vce + emitter drop)). I did an LTSpice sim with 2n3904 and got 32.4mA, for 2n2222 got 27.8mA, both using 500 ohm load in place of the LEDs.

Answer (score 3):

The 3.2V at 20mA is typical or nominal. Unless you get leds binned for voltage/current you are getting a mix of leds that will not be identical and perfect. You get what you pay for. Not that the leds are bad, a grab bag of leds just isn't the ideal for precision designs.

And your resistor will be the same. 20 to 1 percent tolerance of the stated value. At 20% an 82 ohm resistor can be 65.6 to 98.4 ohms. And that's before any drift from heat. Which should be unlikely here.

And the transistor will have a small drop too. And the wires if undersized.

So work around it. For a one off design, just adjust the resistor until you get what you want current wise. Or measure each led and adjust the resistor accordingly. Measure the resistor to ensure what it's actual resistance is.

Answer (score 1):

LEDs, or semiconductors in general, have a strong negative temperature coefficient. This means that as soon as they get hot, their resistance drops sharply. Therefore, LEDs should not be operated at constant voltage, as this promotes a kind of self-destruction. Sure, you can limit the current with a current mirror or emitter follower, but that is a waste of energy. My tip at this point is to use a switching regulator and connect it as a current limiter.

Forgive me for not giving you any concrete examples here, but I think doing your homework would not help much.

Answer (score 0):

All of the previous answers looked at variations in the LED voltage drop characteristics, resistor tolerance, etc.  But the design is also sensitive to variations in the 24 volt supply.  Calculations are left as an exercise for the student, of course.  For example, however, if the diodes dropped 3.2 volts as originally conjectured, a supply voltage of 24.82 would explain the unexpectedly high current.

Answer (score -1):

Have you measured power under pulsed power circumstance? 
Some led are canonically designed to work in PWM then in continuous mode them drain an uncertain amounts of energy. More considering you're using a bare resistor as current source not a current mirror as it should,
Try powering them with a more fine power topology. 50% PWM at 1Khz aprox will be fine. and maybe double the current source using a resistor and a current mirror on the other side. that would work, considering you may be using a switched supply in the first place.
I hope this analysis can be further improved, imho
Of course you can furthen your analysis of what voltage drop each led actually has, probably you're feeding 1 or 2 extra volts into the system which can easily exponentiate led power. Maybe you can feed a few more/less miliamps replacing the resistor but you may definitely need a current source for the large number of leds whose voltage drop may vary in the order of milivolts individually causing the whole strip to produce more power than calculated and extra heat,
One more thing. the 82Ω resistor is 1/8w. heat may not be noticeable at first but it may worsen overtime, try not using carbon resistor but instead use a steady 1 watt metal resistor. that may be a temporary solution. measure for resistor value changes after each test, you may be forcing the resistor to an amount of joules hardly calculable for a 24v source. Leds which are in practice 20mA work in the theory with an amount of joules close to 12mA max. if you want no leds offline, lower the whole individual power by 15% minimum; with the adition of the current source and 15% (or more) less than 20mA, your leds will produce a barely noticeable luminous change but them may last for years instead of days like working at 20mA with a resistor as current source.

14mA-17mA will be fine for a 24v source.

drop 1/8W carbon resistor and use 1W metal

replace resistor with negative current source

use both at each ends, film resistor and current mirror

loses regarding current mirror will be rarely noticeable for a 24v source. focus on pdf or similar function for finding an appropiate mean of current the strip will have. Such as the variations in each lead do not lead to overall heat drain